# Phonegap Build doesn't include cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js and facebook-js-sdk.js

Tags: cordova, plugins, build

Why phonegap build (online version) doesn't include cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js and facebook-js-sdk.js anymore, since we did not make any changes in the js inclussion nor in the config.xml file. Try with older version of phonegap (3.0.0) and this generate these files of .ipa but not for apk. thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.phonegap.example"
        versionCode = "10" 
        version     = "1.0.0" >

    <!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

    <name>sssssssss</name>

    <description>
        dasdasdasdasdasa
    </description>

    <!-- FB Connect Section -->
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" /> <!-- FB App ID-->
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="sssss" /> <!-- FB App Namespace-->
    </gap:plugin>

    <author href="https://ssssssss.com" email="ssss@ssss.com">
         ssssssssssssss
    </author>

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin"/>


    <!-- Core Plugin -->

    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="false" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="lightcontent" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="7" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" /> 

    <access origin="*" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />

</widget>
```

In my index.html

```
<!-- cordova -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <!-- cordova facebook plugin -->
        <script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
        <!-- facebook js sdk -->
        <script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try asking this on the phonegap build support forum: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi

Comment: I did but I had no answers yet, thanks

Answer (score 2):

indicating the version of the plugin (0.4.0) the build cloud mode include again the script that did not include (facebook-js-sdk and cdv-plugin-fb-connect)

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.4.0">
```